# naked expression at top level

Tags: haskell

I've been trying to get my head around this parse error on ghci for a while and I can't seem to find an answer online that isn't vague:

```
enrollment :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
enrollment (x:y:z:xs) (a:b:c:as) - if z == c && y == b then True else False

Parse error: naked expression at top level
Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell
```

There were no imports to make typos on, and I've spent ages making little tweaks with no progress!
Thanks

Comment: You wrote `-` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means that at the top level, you usually only define *functions* (as well as datatypes, typeclasses, type instances, etc. but let us ignore that for now).

Now you write:

```
enrollment :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
enrollment (x:y:z:xs) (a:b:c:as) - if z == c && y == b then True else False
--                               ^
```

But as you can see, you did not define a function: indeed there is no equality sign (`=`). So Haskell interprets this like you want to subtract the body of the function from the head of the function.

We can solve the error with:

```
enrollment :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
enrollment (x:y:z:xs) (a:b:c:as) = if z == c && y == b then True else False
--                               ^
```

But now there is still a problem: if one of the two lists contains less than three elements, then the function will error. So we better add a rule for such cases:

```
enrollment :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
enrollment (x:y:z:xs) (a:b:c:as) = if z == c && y == b then True else False
enrollment _ _ = False
```

Furthermore writing `if <expr> then True else False` is a quite verbose version of `<expr>`, so we can rewrite it as:

```
enrollment :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
enrollment (x:y:z:xs) (a:b:c:as) = z == c && y == b
enrollment _ _ = False
```

Or we can - like @JonPurdy says - construct two tuples and compare these, like:

```
enrollment :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
enrollment (x:y:z:xs) (a:b:c:as) = (y, z) == (b, c)
enrollment _ _ = False
```

Comment: Another handy simplification: `z == c && y == b` = `(z, y) == (c, b)` (or maybe clearer, `(y, z) == (b, c)`)